# phpmyadmin not found issue

Tags: debian

hey, i installed phpmyadmin and I go to myip/phpmyadmin/ and sign in, but then it's telling me

The requested URL /phpmyadmin/index.php was not found on this server.

I'm running debian and any suggestions on getting it working would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reconfigure to use Apache 2:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

Try purge phpmyadmin:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin
$ sudo rm -rf /etc/phpmyadmin
$ sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Also(manual configure Apache2):

```
$ sudo ln -fvs /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: tried that aswell as removing the package and reinstalling it multiple times.

Comment: What output "ls -al /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php"?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6586 2008-07-28 14:41 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php

Comment: What error in "/var/log/apache2/error.log"?

Comment: [Thu Feb 17 17:11:28 2011] [error] [client 173.206.129.30] File does not exist: /var/www/phpmyadmin, referer: http://173.192.176.177/phpmyadmin/

Comment: Try purge phpmyadmin

Comment: perfect, the symlink worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this line:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

To:
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: it's already there

Comment: have you restarted apache?

Comment: better use symlink to /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf in /etc/apache2/conf.d directory

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Try also to use login `phpmyadmin` instead of `root`
It works for me